# _blank attribute doesn't get set

Tags: theming

I'm trying to target on the Menu (Bootstrap) a `_blank` attribute.

This is my code. It works on my local machine.

```
if ($variables['url']->isExternal()) {
  $variables['options']['attributes'] = ['target' => '_blank'];
}
```

The HTML target.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">MySite</a>
  </li>
<ul>
```

BUT,

In here is not working because of the "class="first".

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="first">
    <a href="https://example.com/1">Example link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.com/2">Example link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <a href="https://example.com/3">Example link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm missing something, any help? I don't want to install a module for this.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code examples. I have edited the post to show code examples as plain text, but my edits are waiting for peer review.

Comment: What does the class have to do with it? It's not even on the same element.

Comment: Well, the code above works. This is from my local-machine. But , the same code, is not working on a second machine or drupal host site. So, I was thinking that the problem was the "class" element. Maybe, i am wrong.

Comment: I think the `class="first"` is a red herring. More likely, it's related to the context surrounding your conditional: if ($variables['url']->isExternal()) { $variables['options']['attributes'] = ['target' => '_blank']; } Does this run inside a hook? If so, please include the entire code block surrounding this statement.

Comment: Where are you firing your code? What hook?

Answer (score 2):

When you write `$variables['options']['attributes'] = ['target' => '_blank']` you are replacing all `attributes`, never ever do that!

Only set specific keys:
`$variables['options']['attributes']['target'] = '_blank'`.

If that key is an array, append your value:
`$variables['options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'appended_class'`